# How to know what controllers->actions is called in cake shell?

Tags: php, cakephp

My project has a big database. And I have just changed it to `master/slave` database to improve query time. Now I can change between `master/slave` database on `controllers->actions` using URLs.

But now I want to apply that change with cake shell too. I don't know if there's any way to determine which `controllers->actions` are being called in `cake shell?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this page :https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/commands.html

And create your command for change this databases )

Comment: I have a lot of ShellCommand. And i want to list an array of Shell filename, if the executing command in that list, i will use master database. And if not i'll use slave database. I don't want to make change on each command